# Logistic Regression: fit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook

I am applying Logicstics regression, on a dataset where y is boolean and dependent on x.
Following is dataset (I'm sharing Jupyter snapshots):

**1. Data Summary**

[image]

**2. Divided dataset in training and test set. And plotted y vs x**

[image]

**3. Fitting the data**

[image]

I've tried many things based on other [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35996970/typeerror-fit-missing-1-required-positional-argument-y) solutions. But still getting the same error.
Any help will be great here. Thanks.

Comment: Would love to know the reason for downvotes?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
lr = LogisticRegression()
```

Comment: This and 
"lr = LogisticRegression();
lr.fit(X.values.reshape(-1, 1), y.values.ravel())"
worked. Thanks!