# "fit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'" error

Tags: python-3.x, linear-regression, sklearn-pandas

I have been attempting to use sklearn to create some test data for a linear regression model. The error I am getting is 'fit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y''

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X = df[['Avg. Area Income', 'Avg. Area House Age', 'Avg. Area Number of Rooms',
       'Avg. Area Number of Bedrooms', 'Area Population']]

y = df['Price']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.4, random_state=101)

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

lm = LinearRegression

lm.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

I have tried looking at this link 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35996970/typeerror-fit-missing-1-required-positional-argument-y' but I cannot fix it.

Comment: Hi, it is much easier to read and understand you question if it's well formatted and structured. Please check [this guide on how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). In this case code formatting and directly linking to referenced guides would improve the readability greatly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X = df[['Avg. Area Income', 'Avg. Area House Age', 'Avg. Area Number of Rooms',
       'Avg. Area Number of Bedrooms', 'Area Population']]

y = df['Price']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.4, random_state=101)

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

lm = LinearRegression()

lm.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

you forgot `()` after `lm = LinearRegression`

Answer (score -1):

You forgot `()` in the end. The code should be,

```
lm = LinearRegression()
```

and not

```
lm = LinearRegression
```

Comment: This is the same solution as in [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62525700/2227743).