# Python sklearn linear regression error: fit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'"

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I'm very new to Python and scikit-learn. I'm having difficulty working with the scikit-learn Boston data house prices data set. Please find my code below.

Thanks!

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy.stats as stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sklearn

bos = pd.DataFrame(boston.data)
bos.head()

bos.columns = boston.feature_names
bos.head()

boston.target[:5]

bos['PRICE'] = boston.target
bos.head()

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
X = bos.drop('PRICE', axis = 1)
lm = LinearRegression

LinearRegression.fit
lm.fit(X,bos.PRICE) 


TypeError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-52-f9496290723b> in <module>
      1 LinearRegression.fit
----> 2 lm.fit(X,bos.PRICE)

TypeError: fit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: fit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35996970/typeerror-fit-missing-1-required-positional-argument-y)

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `lm = LinearRegression()` and not `lm = LinearRegression`.

You can use  `lm.fit?` to see the signature of the method. You would see that it is

```
Signature: lm.fit(self, X, y, sample_weight=None)
```

So your X is being assigned to self, and bos.PRICE to X, and it is complaining that y is not provided. Seeing the self there should give you an indication that the wrong method is being called.

Comment: Wow, that was simple. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped. Please help accept the answer, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your `lm = LinearRegression` is missing the parentheses, thus the Model Object constructor is not called. Furthermore, you are not correctly fitting the model you just created. The line `LinearRegression.fit` is not needed.

Try the following and see if it helps:

```
import pandas as pd    
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

boston = datasets.load_boston() # loading boston dataset
bos = pd.DataFrame(boston.data) # creating dataframe from loaded data
bos.columns = boston.feature_names

bos['PRICE'] = boston.target
bos.head()

X = bos.drop('PRICE', axis = 1)

lm = LinearRegression() # initializing LinearRegression Model
lm.fit(X,bos.PRICE) # fitting data to our LinearRegression Model
```