# Missing positional argument from KNeighborsRegressor.fit(), but examples show it only taking two

Tags: python, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

The [documentation for KNeighborsRegressor](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsRegressor.html) shows it being used as follows:

```
>>> X = [[0], [1], [2], [3]]
>>> y = [0, 0, 1, 1]
>>> from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsRegressor
>>> neigh = KNeighborsRegressor(n_neighbors=2)
>>> neigh.fit(X, y)
KNeighborsRegressor(...)
```

...with exactly two arguments, `X` and `y`.

---

In my own code, I'm trying to apply this as so:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
X,y=load_boston(return_X_y=True)

from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsRegressor
mod=KNeighborsRegressor
mod.fit(X, y)
KNeighborsRegressor()
mod.predict(X)
```

...but I get an error: `fit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'`

I'm passing both X and y; why does this happen?

Comment: Are you sure you want `mod=KNeighborsRegressor`, not `mod=KNeighborsRegressor()`? This isn't Ruby, where those two are the same: Your code is making `mod` point to the `KNeighborsRegressor` _class itself_, not an instance of that class. And when you call a class method on the class itself instead of on an instance of that class, it requires an extra `self` argument to specify an instance, hence your error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: fit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35996970/typeerror-fit-missing-1-required-positional-argument-y)